# an attributive clause or adverbial clause?

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses, clauses

They give me more time to spend as they see fit.
Here, is “as they see fit” a attributive clause or a adverbial clause?

Comment: Attributives precede the head, but this element follows the verb, so how can it possibly be attributive? "As they see fit" is a preposition phrase functioning as a manner adjunct in clause structure.

Comment: @BillJ  My understanding is that an attributive clause is equivalent to a relative clause, and the there are defining relative clause and non defining clause. In this case, I would say there is a possibility that “as they see fit” functions as a relative clause, modifying the noun “time”, but that being said, I also think it’s possible for it to function as an adverbial clause. While I would like to know whether you think it’s a preposition phrase functioning as an adjunct or a adverbial clause, I would also like to ask how to distinguish the two.

Comment: The term 'attributive' normally applies to modifiers in NP structure, not in clause structure. Defining relative clauses are one type of post-head modifier. Non-defining relatives are not modifiers bu supplements. "As" is a preposition here -- it distinguishes "as they see fit" as a PP, where "as" is the head with a declarative content clause as its complement. The PP then functions as a manner adjunct (your adverbial). It can't be a relative clause because there is no (overt or covert) R element anaphorically linked to the head noun.

Comment: @BillJ What if here “as” is a conjunction? If that’s the case, then this could be a adverbial clause. And why it can’t be a relative clause if “as” is the relative pronoun? I am really confused about what “as” is here, as well as curious as to how you can locate the exact part of speech of it.